# Add Dictionary to Class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I would like to have my character add items to their inventory from a dictionary, however when I add them it only gives me the 'value' return, not the 'key' as well. I would like to use both for different parts of the game "You are holding 'key', it does 'value' damage" for example.

I think I understand this is adding the dictionaries 'value' because my inventory type is a 'list', but having trouble finding a simple way to add the dictionary items.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
from random import randint

class Character:
    # Instantiates each character with personality traits
    def __init__(self, name, health, lives, gender, inventory):
        self.name = name
        self.health = int(health)
        self.lives = int(lives)
        self.gender = gender
        self.inventory = []


inventoryitems = {
    'Breadstick': randint(0,5), 
    'Magic Axe': randint(50,100), 
    'Tiny Fists': randint(0,25),
    'Sword': randint(15,30)
    }

player = Character("Kate", 100, 3, 'female',None)

player.inventory.append(inventoryitems['Magic Axe'])
player.inventory.append(inventoryitems['Breadstick'])
print(player.inventory)
```

Comment: Maybe append tuples to the `inventory` list, like `player.inventory.append(('Magic Axe', inventoryitems['Magic Axe']))`. Or just append the item name, and then use `inventory` and `inventoryitems` to get the value whenever you need it.

Comment: Why you dont use a dictonary in your class to ?

Comment: @bboumend can you give me an example? I think that would be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dictionary into your class is simple and then you can generate list of item by name using player.inventory.keys(), you also can access item in a very easy and fast way later by doing player.inventory['object_name']

```
from random import randint

class Character:
    # Instantiates each character with personality traits
    def __init__(self, name, health, lives, gender, inventory):
        self.name = name
        self.health = int(health)
        self.lives = int(lives)
        self.gender = gender
        self.inventory = {}


inventoryitems = {
    'Breadstick': randint(0,5), 
    'Magic Axe': randint(50,100), 
    'Tiny Fists': randint(0,25),
    'Sword': randint(15,30)
    }

player = Character("Kate", 100, 3, 'female',None)

player.inventory['Magic Axe'] = inventoryitems['Magic Axe']
player.inventory['Breadstick'] = inventoryitems['Breadstick']
print(player.inventory)
```

Comment: Note that your character can now carry only one `Magic Axe`!

Comment: oh you are correct @NOhs, I dont see a way to append to this dictionary o.O

Comment: Thats ok with me, thanks! But maybe for others who view this do you have a solution for this @NOhs?

Comment: You can solve this by using a list as value in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `items()` to iterate over both the keys and the values at the same time:

```
from random import randint

class Character:
    # Instantiates each character with personality traits
    def __init__(self, name, health, lives, gender, inventory):
        self.name = name
        self.health = int(health)
        self.lives = int(lives)
        self.gender = gender
        self.inventory = []


inventoryitems = {
    'Breadstick': randint(0,5), 
    'Magic Axe': randint(50,100), 
    'Tiny Fists': randint(0,25),
    'Sword': randint(15,30)
}

player = Character("Kate", 100, 3, 'female',None)

# item will be a (key, value) pair
for item in inventoryitems.items():
    player.inventory.append(item)

# or if you only want to add specific items
items_to_add = ['Breadstick', 'Magic Axe']
for item in items_to_add:
    player.inventory.append((item, inventoryitems[item]))

print(player.inventory)
```

will print e.g.

```
[('Breadstick', 5), ('Magic Axe', 51), ('Tiny Fists', 21), ('Sword', 17), ('Breadstick', 5), ('Magic Axe', 51)]
```

Note how adding items twice will not apply new random values to each one, which might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you I tried this, I was getting strange results adding (item), it would override all items with 'Breadstick' for example.

Comment: @JamesVella how did you "add item" ??? The above is the obvious solution, really - with the exception that directly exposing `Character.inventory` breaks encapsulation (cf law of demeter) but that's another topic.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers i changed the lines: player.inventory.append(item) to: player.inventory.append('Breadstick'). I see whats going on now but I would like to add one of those items at a time depending on what they find. Excuse my ignorance, Im still learning and forget some of the basics at times, I end up re-reading things I read before and its quite an up hill battle at times

Comment: `player.inventory.append('Breadstick')` cannot "override all items" if `inventory` is a list.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers thank you for the update, I think this is actually what Im looking for. Sorry to be a pain but can I add this to a character by default as well, such as: kingsguard = Character("The Kings Guard", 150, 1, 'male', inventoryitems['Sword']) ... I get [] empty list for this starting character

Comment: In your `__init__` function you set your inventory explicitly to `[]`. You need to change this.